# retrieving data from firebase in react- redux app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, axios

firebase rules

```
{
  "rules": {
      "ingredients": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
      },
     "orders": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": ["userId"]
      } 
  }
}
```

firebase data

```
{
  "ingredients" : {
    "bacon" : 0,
    "cheese" : 0,
    "meat" : 0,
    "salad" : 0
  },
  "orders" : {
    "-M-gRBK60ImmEg55J2lC" : {
      "ingredients" : {
        "bacon" : 0,
        "cheese" : 0,
        "meat" : 1,
        "salad" : 1
      },
      "orderData" : {
        "country" : "a",
        "deliveryMethod" : "fastest",
        "email" : "a@a.com",
        "name" : "a",
        "street" : "aa",
        "zipcode" : "11111"
      },
      "price" : 1.8,
      "userId" : "LyKBp44aSgPiGPdKvClUNtddJ7G3"
    }
  }
}
```

here i want to retrieve orders from firebase and filter it according to userId 
to display user specific orders 
but it fails and console.log(res.data) give me empty obj { }
instead of the orders .. there's no error message 
.. what is the problem here ??

```
export const fetchOrders = (token, userId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchOrdersStart()); // to set loading to true 
        const queryParams = '?auth=' + token + '&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="' + userId + '"';
        axios.get( '/orders.json' + queryParams)
        .then( res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          const fetchedOrders = [];
          for ( let key in res.data ) {
            fetchedOrders.push( {
              ...res.data[key], 
              id: key 
            } );
          }
          dispatch(fetchOrdersSuccess(fetchedOrders));
      } )
      .catch( err => {
        dispatch(fetchOrdersFail(err));
      } );
  };
};
```

Comment: "it fails" -> what precisely goes wrong? Do you get an error message? No results? Also: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Your security rules for `orders` require `"auth != null"` to read, but your code doesn't seem to send authentication information anywhere. You can easily test if that is the cause of the problem by setting the read rule to `true` temporarily. If it is the problem, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth